# difference betweens php socket I/O functions

Tags: php, sockets

Long story short, there're so many socket I/O functions in php seems doing the same thing.

So I'm wondering is there any difference between `fread()` and `stream_get_contents()` and `stream_socket_recvfrom()` ?

Also `fwrite()` and `stream_socket_sendto()`, they're all look same, which should I choice ?

Thank you for viewing my question, and I will appreciate for any advice~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inconsistency and redundancy seem to be hallmarks of PHP unfortunately: you do have a lot from which to choose. And streams are just plain confusing frankly.

I think what's important to keep in mind in this case is that some functions that operate on sockets are *generic* and others are more *specific*. The [PHP streams](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.stream.php) API attempts to provide a way to generalize file/network operations and therefore provides generic functions for common operations such as `fwrite` and `fread`. That's why you can `fopen` a Web page, local file or compressed archive all with the same function. However the `stream_socket_*()` family of functions are more specific and provide extra functionality that pertain only to sockets. For example, the `stream_socket_recvfrom()` and `stream_socket_sendto()` calls allow for out-of-band data channels (essentially a way to multiplex another data stream using a single connection).

I'll try to compare/contrast some of the generic versus specific PHP functions as they apply to sockets.

- `fopen()` vs `stream_socket_client()`: You can `fopen` a TCP connection for example but suppose you wanted to get more information about the connection status or handle timeouts. The `stream_socket_client()` function allows you to set connection timeout status and get more advanced error feedback when a connection is unsuccessful. It also allows you to connect asynchronously (i.e. in non-blocking mode).
- `fread()/fwrite()` vs `stream_socket_sendto()/stream_socket_recvfrom()`: As already stated you can receive/send out-of-band data using the later set of functions; you can also encapsulate the connection and read/write operations into a single call.
- `fclose()` vs `stream_socket_shutdown()`: These aren't exactly analogous but the names imply something similar. You still want to call `fclose` to free the socket and any associated memory. The function of `stream_socket_shutdown` is to shutdown a channel (either send or receive) in the underlying TCP connection. For example, you can stop sending on a full-duplex socket but still keep reading.

Note: this next comparison isn't really a comparison between a generic, stream function and a socket-specific function. It is a comparison of two generic stream functions that happen to do different things. I included it since you mentioned it in the question.

- `fread()` vs `stream_get_contents()`: `fread` reads up to a pre-determined amount of bytes; `stream_get_contents` reads the remaining data on the stream. You can see this is pretty much a convenience function that can improve performance. However there are times when you need to stream the data in using `fread` such as when you expect a lot of data that can't fit into main memory.

Hopefully you get the idea. A lot of this parallels the structure of the lower-level programming interfaces. In Linux, for example, the interfaces for working with I/O devices are polymorphic. You can `read()` on a file, domain socket, stream socket, datagram socket, pipe, fifo, ETC. However there are functions for specifically operating on a certain type of I/O device (e.g. `send()` is called only on sockets).

I would recommend choosing what best fits your needs and not predispose yourself to any general rules regarding what to use. For example, if you need to `GET` a Web page over HTTP, just use `file_get_contents`. If you know the response is going to be huge you might want to `fopen` it and stream the result to disk. If you need to implement a client for a custom protocol then I would use the more specific stream socket family of functions that give you more fine tuned control.

Comment: Thank you for this long long answer, what about socket family functions compare to stream family functions ? for example `socket_recv()` `socket_read()` v.s. `fread()`, `socket_send()` `socket_write()` v.s. `fwrite()` ?

Comment: @NotUser9123 for most any case, you can ignore the `socket_*` functions and use the stream API. PHP 8 will soon deprecate the confusing `resource` type entirely.